# SSRS 2008R2 Matrix Column Group Totals

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am using a Matrix control in SSRS 2008R2 and I am trying to create totals for my column groupings. Here's a sample of my Matrix layout:

```
       January          February         March              TOTALS
   2011     2012     2011    2012     2011   2012       2011      2012
```

My question is, How do I get the totals column to function as indicated, above? The report will default to a comparison of current year and previous year. Additional question, What if I had multiple years? How would I be able to get the column totals by year? For example:

```
      January           February          March             TOTALS
2011  2012  2013   2011  2012  2013  2011  2012  2013   2011  2012  2013
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]First take a matrix table.. assign dataset to it.. go to column group properties delete blank group in it.. then column will appear like list... then right clik on column list, add a column inside the group.. here in second column add parent grouping with year... next in 1st column add parent grouping with month and child grouping with Year![enter image description here][2]..